# compatibility of ROS with Intel atom tunnel creek and xtion pro live sensor

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, xtion, intel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an **intel atom tunnel creek processor (E640)** for my project and a **xtion pro live sensor**.And I am planning to implement SLAM. So will the intel atom creek handle the extensive processing ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192591/compatibility-of-ros-with-intel-atom-tunnel-creek-and-xtion-pro-live-sensor/) by [Shubham Garg](https://answers.ros.org/users/20186/shubham-garg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-09-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That processor is not likely to run any existing 3D or 2D SLAM implementation at any reasonable sort of framerate. In fact, I'm guessing it would likely struggle with just running the openni driver and pulling in pointcloud data from the Xtion, but that would be up to you to verify.

If this is running on a robot, you may have some luck grabbing the pointcloud, or even just the depth and rgb image streams on this processor, and doing the SLAM processing remotely on a beefier PC.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shubham Garg](https://answers.ros.org/users/20186/shubham-garg/) on 2014-09-13**:
Thanks a lot for your quick response.
I have one more option. Can I can use **Intel atom N2800 processor** for performing SLAM ??  I am thinking to use this board *http://click.intel.com/edc/development-kit-norco-bis-6630-intelr-atomtm-processor-n2800-rev-2.html*

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-09-13**:
It all depends - 2D, 3D, realtime or offline, I gave you a basic overview but beyond that you'd have to experiment.

**Comment by [Shubham Garg](https://answers.ros.org/users/20186/shubham-garg/) on 2014-09-15**:
Can you please tell me best possible intel atom processor for running SLAM ??